# "Have a nice ride to work"

Tags: phrases

Is it OK to say the following to somebody who is going to work on a bike?

> “Have a nice ride to work!”

How can I wish someone a good time while he/she is on her way to work?

Comment: Are they riding a bike or similar to go to work?

Comment: @JamesK Yes, they’re going to work by bicycle

Answer (score 1):

In the given context (going to work on a bike), it is correct. Riding a bike can be an enjoyable experience.  I would not use it if they were going by train or bus.

It might be more natural to say "Have a nice day at work", if you are not going to see them until they finish work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is usual to make such a wish for somebody, but grammatically it is correct.

It might be more suitable to be used as a sarcastic sympathetic joke, e.g. when the bus is super-crowded.

---

If you want to make a wish when departing somebody, you may use the generic:

> Have a nice day!

or

> Have an easy day!

or even:

> Have fun!